# Selenium IDE is not displaying in firefox version 47.0.1

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have installed firefox version 47.0.1 in my machine and installed selenium IDE add on. but it didnt displaying. I have also tried 45.0.2, 48.0 versions of FF. In which version of FF selenium IDE will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the IDE successfully installed then Follow Below steps :

1. click Menus of Firefox (displaying 3 bars in top right corner of FF)
2. Click on customize
3. Your installed addons will display in left side panel
4. Click and Hold the Selenium IDE and Move to the Toolbar
5. Exit Customize

As i know It supports all FF version

I'm using  Selenium_IDE 2.9.1 in Firefox v52